# Storing the order of embedded documents in a separated array

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, meteor

I have a set of objects that the user can sort arbitrarily. I would like to make my client remember the sorting of the set of objects so that when the user visits the page again the ordering he/she chose will be preserved. However, the client-side framework should also be able to quickly lookup the objects from whatever array/hashmap they are stored in based upon the ordering. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found for doing this is using an array that stores the IDs of the array in the particular order I wanted. From there, I can access the array of objects I wanted by converting the array to a hashmap using Underscore.js.